# Universally skip validation params on required inputs

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

How to make some button which can skip web required validation(but still I want to process all data, so immediate and so on cannot be true).

Important is that it must be universal. At the moment I am using in every required field condition with some request param. Code example below

```
<p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.data.exampleData1}" 
             required="#{param['onlySave'] == null}"/>
<p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.data.exampleData2}" 
             required="#{param['onlySave'] == null}"/>
<p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.data.exampleData3}" 
             required="#{param['onlySave'] == null}"/>

<p:commandButton value="Zapisz zmiany"
                 action="#{cc.attrs.controller.save()}"
                 update="@form">
   <f:param name="onlySave" value="true"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

This solution is fine cause I can in every page just add this param to button and it skips validation, but when my save button not making any redirect, in case of failed some java validation in save method, I am just adding some message without redirect and then I lost all required styles from inputs.

Is there any possibility to set `onlySave` param to `null` in save method when validation failed or maybe some better solutions?

**Edit:** Balus answer great, but with bean validation like:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^([^0-9]*)$", message = "only non numbers")
String field;
```

It processes to bean all data beyond that field. The best would be ignore only required field property, not validation etc.

**Edit2:**

```
<tr>
    <td class="label">
        <p:outputLabel id="label" for="#{cc.attrs.componentId}" value="#{cc.attrs.label}"/>
    </td>
    <td class="value">
        <cc:insertChildren/> --here component with componentId
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="errorMessage">
    <td class="label"/>
    <td class="value">
        <p:message id="error" for="#{cc.attrs.componentId}" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your concrete functional requirement is bit hard to digest, but I believe you're looking for http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/ignoreValidationFailed Is this true?

Comment: wow, its almost perfect, only one problem. When I am using this tag and write in some field for example numbers in non number field bean: @Pattern(regexp = "^([^0-9]*)$", message = "numbers!!") it not process data as it suposed to be. But every other field is processed. It even not giving me any info.

Comment: So, your concrete functional requirement is to set a common attribute on all components of the given type from a single place? Perhaps you need http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/massAttribute?

Comment: am I able to change value of massive argument when I click some specific button like with the f:param? And then can I change its value again in action method used in this specifiv button, after failure custom validation  ?

Comment: If it's an EL expression referencing the desired value, yes.

Comment: U meant massAttribute value="#{someBean.value}" ? I am using for each view one viewScoped controller, so this someBean should be sessionScoped and i need to inject it to all web controllers, so I could controll its value ? And I cannot use name='required' because, some fields need to be required some not. I cannot set massive arg for all at once i hope there is eaisly way to workaround

Comment: You didn't cover that problem during your `o:ignoreValidationFailed` test. It would have the same "problem".

Comment: Do you want a "Save as draft" button?  If so, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26613408/1980659).

Comment: Check the below answer of mine, i have tested also.

Comment: @ForguesR Yes it is save as draft, but on same page I have also normal save button, and every input must be prepared if its only draft(ignoring required,but not ignoring valdiators/converters) or full save(cannot ignore nothing). This validator is annotaded with FacesValidator and class implements Validator ? You are adding it to every field which is required to true ? What with some converters? if some required field allow only numbers, and u enter letters, do it ll stop whole process ?

Comment: It can be added to every field and activated when necessary.  You might be interested wrapping the "fields" you are using inside a composite components with this validator (stay DRY).  It works very well with converters and other validators.

Comment: I have carefully re-read your question and I believe your root problem is the following: *"then I lost all required styles from inputs"*, that this is basically the sole reason you want to toggle forth and back the `required` attribute even though those fields are not required at all. What exactly do you mean with "required styles"? The asterisks? The highlighting? Another potential problem is that you're performing validation in an action method instead of in a regular validator capable of marking inputs invalid. What kind of validation exactly is it, that you're executing in action method?

Comment: [continued] If you're absolutely positive that the validation must be done in action method, perhaps this is what you're basically looking for as to marking the inputs invalid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012225/jsf-validation-in-action-phase

Comment: Pages are based on big number of inputs, which are wrapped (code in first post edit2). Problem is only with this styles, this works very fine I am just loosing styles (The background of inputs are not colored, and text is not bolded). My buttons updates @form cause i need to see required failure or converters failure messages.

Comment: To sum up, the best would be updating only error components which shows some converters/required failures, and border of inputs(on failures border are getting red color).

Comment: When I update whole inputs(like with @form) I am loosing thoose styles of background(cause in f:param required is forced to false). In second hand when I dont update input i ll not lost required validation. So I need to update only one parameter 'required' inside inputs -.-

Comment: I'm still not getting the concrete functional requirement. I only start to believe more and more that your misconception is that the `required` attribute is also evaluated during render response. In any case, did the link in my previous comment help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the best solution i figured out is:

```
//p:label and p:message with property for=someId for each input above
<p:inputText id="someId" value="#{cc.attrs.data.exampleData1}" 
         required="#{param['onlySave'] == null}"/>
<p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.data.exampleData2}" 
         required="#{param['onlySave'] == null}"/>
<p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.data.exampleData3}" 
         required="#{param['onlySave'] == null}"/>

<p:commandButton value="save only"
             action="#{cc.attrs.controller.save()}"
             update="@(.ui-message,.ui-outputlabel)">
   <f:param name="onlySave" value="true"/>
</p:commandButton>

<p:commandButton value="accept button"
             action="#{cc.attrs.controller.accept()}"
             update="@form">
</p:commandButton>
```

The save button just updates only all errors and labels, so I am able to see converters errors etc, but I dont lost required styles on inputs. In this example I just lost red color of input borders.

If u re using * in labels for required fields, dont update .ui-outputlabel

Answer (score 0):

Please see below modified code for required fields. You can use #{empty param.onlySave} for the fields which you want to skip the validation and as per your requirements.

```
<p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.data.exampleData1}" 
             required="#{not empty param.onlySave}"/>
<p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.data.exampleData2}" 
             required="#{not empty param.onlySave}"/>
<p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.data.exampleData3}" 
             required="#{not empty param.onlySave}"/>

<p:commandButton value="Zapisz zmiany"
                 action="#{cc.attrs.controller.save()}"
                 update="@form">
   <f:param name="onlySave" value="true"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between that and mine example

Answer (score -1):

I figured out a solution :

**JSF page**

```
<h:form id="form" prependId="false">
            <c:if test="#{param['onlySave'] eq  true}">
                <c:set  value="#{false}"  target="#{myBean}" property="required"/>
            </c:if>
            <p:inputText value="#{myBean.required}"/>
            <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
            <p:inputText id="data1" value="#{myBean.data1}"   
                         required="#{myBean.required}" />
            <p:inputText  id="data2" value="#{myBean.data2}" 
                          required="#{myBean.required}"/>
            <p:inputText id="data3" value="#{myBean.data3}" 
                         required="#{myBean.required}"/>

            <p:commandButton value="Zapisz zmiany"
                             action="#{myBean.save}" />
        </h:form>
```

**Bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements  Serializable{

    private String data1, data2, data3;
    private boolean required;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        required = true;
    }

    public void save() {
        System.out.println(data1+", "+data2+", "+data3);
        required = false;
        //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Info","Saved"));
       //  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("onlySave", "false");// FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("onlySave"));
    }

// ... Getters & Setters
}
```

Comment: Its smth like Balus sugested. I would make the MyBean for sessionScope and use it everywhere. But still its not so universal, there ll be need to inject this controller to every controller in app and implement state in every save method if it passed validation. This is some solution, but it isnt simple as it could be(atleast i belive in that :) )

Comment: If You have a template then you can add this part `<c:if test="#{param['onlySave'] eq  true}">
                <c:set  value="#{false}"  target="#{myBean}" property="required"/>
            </c:if>` in it and make `myBean` is session scoped,thats it no need to do the mention part, also you will change the JSF framework you are using to use omnifaces

Comment: Becasue it is smth that Balus sugested before and like I said it ll force to implement code in like 100 controllers, it ll spend me days for implementing and tests.